# Contact card ui not displaying as expected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm currently trying to build a simple Contacs Card myself. I just want a Profile picture on the top left, about a quarter to a third of the width, and the Name + description on the right side.

No matter what i try, it always looks very similar to the screenshot below.

this is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_standard_padding"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    style="@style/AppBaseThemeCardBG">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/nowCardStyle">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/schuckCard"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/schuckHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light"
                android:text="JESCO SCHUCK"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeVeryLarge" />

            <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light"
                android:text="Description" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: failed cardsui]

I'd like the image to be approximately as wide as the description in the action bar. Obviously i brutally failed here

Comment: Just a note, the Card drawable you are using is way to large, i was using this card as well but had the a similar using you are having now. By right the card should stretch to fit your content but card it large and a 9 patch drawable cannot scale smaller than the original size. Tip use photoshop to reduce size. Do change the dimensions as this might affect your drop shadow quality. instead, make the image smaller by dividing and cutting the inner sections.

Comment: @TrueGuidance Thanks for the tipp, I'll probably go with a different 9patch or make one myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my stupid Problem fixed:

In the `ImageView` I have declared `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` which apparently also centers the `ImageView` in my Layout.
When changing the scaleType to `fitStart` I get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use different values for the layout weights.  Like 4 for the image and 6 for the content to give it 40‰ of the cards width

Comment: tryed it, thats a little better... biggest problem is that the picture just sits in the center instead being on the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using cardslib ( https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) to do your card layout. It is very well put together.

Comment: This would be a little overkill. I just need a simple Cards layout. Thanks for the tip anyway! :)